# Pentaho kettle - get all combination of words

Tags: javascript, java, pentaho, kettle

How can I get all possible combination of words through pentaho kettle. Is there a step that does this?

For example - if I have 3 word Apple , Banana , Orange

I need all unique combinations of those words I.e.

- comb1 = Apple ;
- Comb2 = Banana ;
- Comb3 = Orange ;
- Comb4 = Apple + Banana ;
- Comb5 = Apple + Orange ;
- Comb6 = Banana + Orange ;
- Comb7 = Banana + Apple ;
- Comb8 = Orange + Apple ;
- Comb9 = Orange + Banana ;
- Comb10 = Apple + Banana + Orange ;
- Comb11 = Apple + Orange + Banana ;
- Comb12 = Banana + Orange + Apple ;
- Comb13 = Banana + Apple + Orange ;
- Comb14 = Orange + Apple + Banana ;
- Comb15 = Orange + Banana + Apple ;

I need this to be dynamic I.e. combination to be generated depending upon a no of words supplied.

Thanks!

Comment: for fixed set of words you can create a logic and generate it.

Comment: see if this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809192/8307456 answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDI you need to use 'Modified Java Script Value' step. Because there have no default PDI step to do that. I have prepared a transformation for you. You can get help from this transformation. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTq8XFRHNJ6jTJJCZNTQLDRYJpIeTrGb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks ...that was helpful. The only thing is there a way that we can prepand "comb1 = " to every combination? the numberical value after comb will increase in a +1 fashion like i mentioned above in my question. it depends on the number of combination.
i tried modifying as below but it gives "Comb0 =" always.
perm.push("Comb"+ k +"=" + curr_perm);

Comment: Thats means your want final result should be like 1st row is "com1=Apple" and 2nd row is "com2=Banana" ...........?

Comment: I have modified transformation. Please download again. I did this using PDI step for your better understanding in PDI.

Comment: ...Thanks so much. It helped alot.