# Pentaho Kettle - dynamic javascript

Tags: javascript, etl, pentaho, kettle, pdi

Is there a way to get the javascript script values in the Modified Java Script Value dynamically ? I have transformation (transformation 1) that creates some values/javascript variables as below which i need to use in the Modified Java Script Value step of an other transformation (transformation 2) which will process the data according to the values/variable created by the transformation 1.

Transformation 1 looks like as below: (number of var i.e. variable that is created by this transformation is dynamic. currently i mention only 11 var but, it could be 100+ as well depending on the input received) and the real values of A,B and C is to be fetched and processed by transformation 2.

- var new_A = "Alphabet=" + A ;
- var new_b = "Alphabet=" + B ;
- var new_C = "Alphabet=" + C ;
- var comb1 = new_A ;
- var Comb2 = new_B ;
- var Comb3 = new_C ;
- var Comb4 = new_A + new_B ;
- var Comb5 = new_A + new_C ;
- var Comb6 = new_B + new_C ;
- var Comb7 = new_B + new_A ;
- var Comb8 = new_C + new_A ;
- var Comb9 = new_C + new_B ;
- var Comb10 = new_A + new_B + new_C ;
- var Comb11 = new_A + new_C + new_B ;

i tried some ways but, it seems to doesn't work. I tried ETL metadata injection but, seems it is not working for javascript step as well.

Comment: In short, you need a way to transfer variables/parameter from one transformation to another transformation.

Comment: @Runa yes, that is correct. i do need to transfer those variable from one to another transformation to process it further. The variable (output) i need to transfer is kind of a similar to what you mentioned in (with just a little modification as i mentioned above) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799395/pentaho-kettle-get-all-combination-of-words/63809794?noredirect=1#comment112865565_63809794

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a solution for you. Get the files from [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EX1fRWG3ISr-DumxJr_HG4M_zuxRLYdi?usp=sharing)

MainJob Name is 'MainCombinationJob.kjb'.
I have also attach the output log file i found after run this job.

Comment: Thank you for creating a solution for me. However, to explain my problem statement better, I have created a sample ktr files and issue for which I am seeking help for. Please download the file from this link and let me know if that makes my question more understatle - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1FleiLx3-IHTNZ-LEAJ_MuFdbDwi76Pt6

Comment: Can you please tell me the PDI version you are using? I did not able to open your transformation in PDI 7.0.

Comment: i am using 7.1 PDI version. I have pasted the content of both files (transformation1 and transformation2) in the doc format. can you download those file from the same link (above) and save the content of those files in the ktr file? and see if that helps

Comment: ...were you able to open it?